# sencha touch app layout does not change to landscape

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a basic app using sencha touch that take user from one view to another. When I change my simulator to landscape for some reasons its layout stays the same still showing protrait. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't switch, but you could attach a handler to the `orientation` event in ST2 to see if it is firing at all. Read the docs on [orientation in native apps here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/native_apis-section-5).

Answer (score 0):

Add an orientationchange event on the Viewport:

```
initialize: function () {
    // Add a Listener. Listen for [Viewport ~ Orientation] Change.
    Ext.Viewport.on('orientationchange', 'handleOrientationChange', this, {buffer: 50 });
    this.callParent(arguments);
},
handleOrientationChange: function(){
    console.log('handleOrientationChange');
    // Execute the code that needs to fire on Orientation Change.
}
```